# Instead of a battery, can I connect this light to a DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, dc, light

I bought this LED video light recently, which to my surprise doesn't have a DC power / wall wart input to connect it to mains power. Instead, you're required to use a 7.4V Sony 970 series camera battery:

[image: Godox LEDP120C]

Needless to say, I don't have the correct battery and don't want to shell out for one. However, I have a decent bench PSU - can I simply dial it to 7.4V and connect it (using croc clips or the like) to the battery power terminals on the light? If not, what circuit/modifications would I need to make?

**[UPDATE 20/10/2017]** - Okay, I took the plunge and connected it up. The light functions for a second or two, and then the low battery indicator comes and and the light shut off. If I toggle the power on the PSU the same thing happens - light comes on for a moment, then shuts down due to (presumably) a low-battery shutoff feature. Any good ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: I don't see why not. But if you have a bench PSU hook it up and bring up the voltage slowly and see...

Comment: @Trevor If it is designed to work with a 7.4V battery there is no need to slowly bring up the voltage. Just make sure your PSU can provide enough current.

Comment: @Piglet you are right it should, but better to watch the first time and shut off the power than cook the thing.

Comment: afaik sony even sells adapters that go in place of a battery

Comment: As it is made for a LiIon battery it should tolerate Vin of about 6V to 8.4V. ie anything in the say 6.5 - 7.5V range should be fine. Max power is stated to be 12W or about 2A input current. A suitably large capacitor to handle surges may be a good idea - eg power supply  MAY sag at turn on of LEDs.

Comment: @Trevor If you exceed the maximum voltage your device will die. no matter how fast you reach that voltage ;)

Comment: @Piglet, well duh... I did not suggest going above that.. but valid point. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Okay, I took the plunge - but it seems to have a low-battery shutoff feature that prevents the light from remaining on - see the updated question. Any ideas on how to bypass this?

Comment: Does your bench power supply have an adjustable current limit?  If so, what is the current limit set to?  And how much current does that light need? LiIon batteries can supply a lot of current.

Comment: @jameslarge I’ve tried it for a few values up to 3.2A, which is my supply’s maximum.

Comment: ...aaaand at 6.4A, with my two outputs in parallel. No luck.

Comment: @WesleyLee - I like your thinking. Just tried it at 8V, but same result unfortunately!

Comment: Is one of those plastic "teeth" operating a switch limiting the time on? or, not operating a switch....